# Getting variants from admin api returns 'options' value inconsistently?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

When I fetch products from the admin api from the `admin/product_listings` endpoint, within each variant, I'll get `options` in as an `option_values` array:

```
variants: [
  {
    title: 'etc etc'
    option_values: [{ name:'xxx', value: 'yyy'}]
  }
]
```

Getting variants from the `'/admin/variants/#{variant_id}.json` endpoint however, yields me the `options` as three individual keys:

```
variants: [
  {
    title: 'etc etc'
    option1: 'yyy',
    option2: null,
    option3: null
  }
]
```

Is there a reason behind this design decision?

Comment: There's always *a* reason, but I have no idea what it is or if it's a *good* reason. Shopify has inconsistent formats all over the place - for example, on the frontend there are 3 different JSON formats for products: `{{ product | json }}` is not quite the same as what you get at the `product-handle.js` endpoint and both are quite different from what you get at the `product-handle.json` endpoint.

Comment: Welp, just means that I need to spend time making all data structure consistent with each other.

Comment: {{ product | json }} differs since it is generated by the server side Liquid parse. Any calls to .json endpoints are a completely different beast, and hence they differ from that. Years ago, when scraping become a thing, Shopify had to tighten things up to avoid leaking what some businesses would call their IP. Due to those layered in, globbed on changes over time, one has to be on one's toes to manage. Options are always a pain, like any interleaved dependency hash will be.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Is suppose, the most befitting quote for a situation like this is: "such is life".